# Can you add a column to show the Parent of a Work Item in a flat list Azure DevOps query?

Tags: azure-devops

In DevOps, I'd like to have a flat list query of work list items, and the parent of that work item in a separate column. While tree view works in retrieving a hierarchy of parent items filtered by the child item, I'd simply like a flat list of tasks with a User Story/Bug column to the right (possibly even the feature of that User Story/Bug in another adjacent column). I can't find anything in the DevOps documentation to accomplish this. Can someone push me in the right direction?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there any way to export the Parent Work ID in AzureDevOps into Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57058632/is-there-any-way-to-export-the-parent-work-id-in-azuredevops-into-excel)

Comment: This can be achieved using a new feature, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57058632/is-there-any-way-to-export-the-parent-work-id-in-azuredevops-into-excel/59375457#59375457

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Can you add a column to show the Parent of a Work Item in a flat list DevOps query?

I am afraid you could not add a column to show the Parent of a Work Item in a flat list DevOps query. That because there is no **Parent id** column in the column options.

You can custom a field (like Parent Id) in the work item when parent was assigned, like:

[image]

We can sort via the custom fields and get a list of all the parent work items first.

Besides, there is a similar user voice about it, you can vote and add your comments for this feedback. When there are enough communities vote and add comments for this feedback, the product team member will take this feedback seriously:

~~["Parent ID" as Column Option in Queries](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/398228/parent-id-as-column-option-in-queries.html)~~

The feedback suggestion that has the most votes is this one: [Add “Parent” column to Queries as well](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/641610/add-parent-column-to-queries-as-well-particularly.html)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Note that new functionality has been added to allow Parent to be included in the query output.