# Is there any way to export the Parent Work ID in AzureDevOps into Excel

Tags: excel, azure-devops

I have connected excel with AzureDevOps, as explained by microsoft 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/backlogs/office/bulk-add-modify-work-items-excel?view=azure-devops

Is it any way possible to export the Parent Work ID in the same row in excel as the actual work item that I am exporting?

What I want to achieve is to sum all remaining work that is left on feature level. This means I need to summarize the remaining work for all tasks under all users stories that belong to this feature.

I could fix this by adding tag of the parent feature in all tasks, but I want a better way.

There can be only one parent. Is there any way to export the parent ID?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excel can`t import an id of linked work item in the same row. In your case, work items have to contain a parent ID in separate field. I see two ways to resolve your issue:

1. Create a new field for parent work item types (e.g. summary work). Then with custom solution fill that field with sum of child work.
2. Create a new field for the child work item types (e.g. parent id). Then with custom solution copy into that field a parent work item id.

Additionally, to avoid customization of your process template you can use Power BI custom reports ([Analyze and report on your work using the new VSTS analytics service : Build 2018](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VXdgjRdtBQI)).

Comment: I don't think that will help me. 
What I want to achieve is to export
ParentWorkID / WorkID / WorkName etc.... in the same excel row. 
As in this way I can easily summaries hours etc... in excel using SUMIF statements. 

When I export tree the parent will be one row, then under it I will have the children. ..
There is no easy way to summarize that type of export.

Comment: @Alex I see your problem and have updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Using excel for analyzing the AzureDevOps work did not really work for all use cases.

 The main reason was the ParentId. But basic graphs its easy to do.

Since then I have started using PowerBI instead. And I have managed to achieve all my requirements. After the initial setup its very straightforward to build custom reports in PowerBI.

Answer (score 0):

Azure DevOps has introduced a new feature to make the Parent column available in queries.

[Add parent field to backlog and queries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/release-notes/2019/sprint-159-update#add-parent-field-to-backlog-and-queries)

"The parent field is now available when viewing backlogs and query results. To add the parent field, use the Column options view."